# Weighted Spearman Rank correlation proof

Tags: correlation, ranking, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I have been searching for alternate measures to compute spearman rank correlation that incorporates some sort of weighting in the calculation. I came across this
[paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-842X.00110) by David C. Blest  on weighted spearman rank correlation where he mentions the following result -

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k} (q_i - i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)(q_i - i) = 1/2\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_i^2$$

where,
$
d_i = q_i - i, 1\leqslant q_i , i \leqslant n. $

$q_i$ (scheme-1) and $i$ (scheme-2, where $i$ is monotonically increasing ) are two schemes of ranking (no ties) a given set of $n$ elements . Therefore, the rank tuple of the $i^{th}$ element is given by $(q_i,i) $.

The relation  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k} (q_i - i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)(q_i - i)$$ is pretty straightforward to prove, but I can't prove how  $$1/2\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_i^2$$ is equal to the other two.
It would be great if somebody can help me work this out.

P.S Any other metric to compute weighted rank correlation is also welcome.

Comment: (1) There is no third equality, which makes it difficult to know what you are asking.  (2) Please provide details of the ranking.  In particular, are ties allowed?  How is $q_i$ related to $i$?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have edited .

Comment: Use $\sum i^p=\sum q_i^p$ for all $p$ (you need the cases $p=1,2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)(q_i-i)&=&\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-q_i+q_i-i)(q_i-i)\\
&=&
\sum_{i=1}^n (q_i-i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-q_i)(q_i-i).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now using  $\sum q_i^2=\sum i^2$ and therefore $\sum q_i(q_i-i)=-\sum i(q_i-i)$, you get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-q_i)(q_i-i)=-\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)(q_i-i),
$$
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
2\sum_{i=1}^n (n+1-i)(q_i-i)=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2.
\end{eqnarray*}